# Logstash pipeline not starting

Tags: elastic-stack

I just started learning Elastic Search and trying to dump IIS logs to ES via logstash and see how it looks in Kibana. I run the logstash without any error but logstash pipeline is not starting.

The output seen in logstash command.
[image]

No errors are logged, therefore I cannot understand what the issue mught be.
Any help?

Comment: `logstash.pipeline - Pipeline main started`. You pipeline has started. If you don't get any documents in ES then probably your Logstash configuration is at fault.